# Does the diatonic scales D major, A major, E major and B minor implement the same notes used by the pentatonic F-sharp minor scale?

Tags: scales, sheet-music, melody

The F# minor pentatonic scale notes are:

> F# A B C# E.

Now I want to know if the D major, A major, E major and B minor scales (all diatonic) implement all the notes used by the F# pentatonic minor scale..

Comment: Have you tried spelling out all the scales you mention to see if they do? (Or don’t)

Comment: What happened to C#m?

Comment: This is kind of like your other question about the minor key with the most double flats in the key signature. It's just a factual question about keys. Why do you ask? It seems like you are working around _some other questions._ The answer is simply: YES. But for what purpose does that help?

Comment: The C#m minor scale goes there as well. I didn't forgot it! And also, why my threads are always downvoted?

Comment: @TechnicGoblin5R: I can't speak directly to the downvoters, as I didn't downvote your question. But I suspect part of the reason for this question is because you're asking something that you already seem to know the answer to, and it's unclear what the broader point is. It's as if you went on the English Language and Usage SE and asked, "Do the words for a feline animal, a thing that you wear on your head, an adjective meaning overweight, and the past tense of the verb 'sit' all end in the letters 'at'?" Well yes, but the point is unclear. I suspect that question would be downvoted there too.

Comment: All you have to do is establish the notes used in each quoted scale. That's simple to find in lots of places. If you already know that information, then the question is rhetorical, and will be no help to future visitors here. Just adding the little word '***WHY***' to the question would make it acceptable, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and this becomes apparent once you determine that the F♯ minor pentatonic minor scale is the same as the A major pentatonic scale. It then makes total sense that the tonic, subdominant and dominant keys (A, D, and E major) share these notes. Further, all of their relative minor keys (F♯, B, C♯ minor, respectively) will also share these notes!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to find the answer is *comparing only the accidentals involved in the key signatures.*

This assumes knowledge of key signatures. If that is where the actual knowledge gap lies, learn key signatures!

`F` sharp minor pentatonic is `F# A B C# E`

Arrange that in ascending fifths `A E B F# C#`

Now list out the addition of sharps to key signatures in ascending fifths and stop when you get a mismatch on the pentatonic set of tones `F# C# G# D#...` the next tone would be `A#` so stop and don't include it.

The keys that include all the tones of `F` sharp minor pentatonic are those with key signatures with the two given sharps `F#` and `C#` but don't alter the natural tones, namely:

- D major and B minor
- A major and F sharp minor
- E major and C sharp minor

It's a tedious description in words, but the method helps illuminate how western tonality is based on perfect fifths.

Closer to reality is you will just "see" these things after internalizing all the key signatures.